# my reservation is deleting itself at /exist,advice?

Tags: spring-boot

my project. upon entering in a reservation and then later editing it via /exist my reservation deleted itself. why and how do i fix it?

url:https://github.com/JonathanDaboush/DivinaPopinaBackEnd.git

assume the entity is stored in the database because i used a select query in mysql and its there.

controller:

```
  @PostMapping("/exist")
    public ResponseEntity createreservationExist(@RequestBody Map<Object, Object> payLoad ) throws URISyntaxException, ParseException {

        long id=(Integer)payLoad.get("id");
        Reservation reservation=reservationServices.getreservationById(id);

        String creditCardNumber="";

        creditCardNumber=(String)payLoad.get("creditCardNumber");
        String note=(String)payLoad.get("note");
        reservation.setNote(note);

        DateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date utilDate=simpleDateFormat.parse((String)payLoad.get("dateOfEvent"));
        Date ofDate=new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        reservation.setName((String)payLoad.get("name"));
        reservation.setDateOfEvent(ofDate);
       ArrayList<Order> orders=new ArrayList<>(reservation.getOrders());
        double total=0;
        double tax=0.15;
        for(int i=0;i<orders.size();i++){
                total+=foodServices.getFoodByName(orders.get(i).getFood()).getPrice()*orders.get(i).getQuantity();
        }

            total=total+(total*tax);
            total=(total * 100) / 100.0;

        Transaction transaction=new Transaction(creditCardNumber,total,reservation);
        try{
        transactionServices.removetransaction(reservation.getTransaction().getId());}
        catch(Exception e){

        }


        reservation.setTransaction(transaction);

        reservationServices.saveReservation(reservation);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

I expected to get my object back from MySQL. I tried debugging and checking if I was improper i got no error messages.

description when i set values it doesn't change values from null they shouldn't event be null as this object already was created.

Comment: Completely aside, do not use the two `Date` classes (`java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`). And by all means avoid `SimpleDateFormat`, a notorious troublemaker of a class. Use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html). All you need is `LocalDate.parse((String)payLoad.get("dateOfEvent"));`, no formatter needed since yyyy-MM-dd is the default format for `LocalDate`. If you can’t change your `Reservation` class to accept a `LocalDate` just now, use `java.sql.Date.valueOf(yourLocalDate)` for conversion.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have this line:

```
transactionServices.removetransaction(reservation.getTransaction().getId());
```

This will delete the transaction from the database. In the entity you have a one-to-one mapping between reservation and transaction with fetch type cascade all:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "reservation_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Reservation reservation;
```

Thats why you reservation will be deleted as well.

Comment: thank you so much i you probably think im overexaggerating but you literally saved my career.